# Empty spaces between Widgets even with setSpacing(0)

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

data = {'dia': 23, 'mes': 8, 'ano': 2017}

class FormConfigBkpBD(QWidget):

    senha = None
    pathLine = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None,instancia=None):
        super(FormConfigBkpBD, self).__init__(parent)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.senha = QLineEdit()
        self.senha.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.senha.setFixedSize(385, 25)

        self.pathLine = QLineEdit()
        self.pathLine.setFixedSize(355,25)

        self.senha.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.pathLine.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pathLine,0,Qt.AlignTop)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.senha,0,Qt.AlignTop)

        self.setWindowTitle("Configuração de Backup - Banco de Dados")
        self.setFixedSize(460,640)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    bd = FormConfigBkpBD()
    bd.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    main()
```

The above code shows only two widgets (`QLineEdit`), the original window has much more widgets, this is only for post here.
Why, even with `setSpacing(0)` and `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` there's a space between widgets?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the combination between the fixed size of your window and the layout you are using. The vertical layout tries to distribute evenly (unless told otherwise) all of its children vertically and fill the whole window.

Here you have two widgets so the first one goes in the first cell and the second one goes in the second cell. Since you haven't set any alignment the default behaviour is present that is top left corner of each cell is where the widget is positioned. The rest is just filling the free space of the parent window which the layout is part of.

If you want not space between the widgets

- either remove the fixed size of the window

  [image]
- or put more widgets in the layout until it's "full".

The first option might not be what you want to do (otherwise you would have probably not set it to fixed size in the first place). The second can be achieved by simply using a [`QSpacerItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html) (vertical one) that will take care of the empty space for you and push the widgets to the top where you want these to be:

```
mainLayout.addStretch(1)
```

You can also add the spacer manually if you need more control over its behaviour:

```
self.spacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding) # or Fixed
mainLayout.addItem(self.spacer)
```

Comment: The alignment **has** been set - to `AlignTop` (the default alignment for a `QVBoxLayout` is actually `AlignVCenter`). I think the OP was expecting *both* widgets to be aligned to the top of the window (rather than the top of their respective cells, which each get half of the total height). The correct way to align them both at the top is to add a spacer to the end of the layout (i.e. `mainLayout.addStretch()`) - then it won't be necessary to explicitly set the alignment.

Comment: Yeah dude, @ekhumoro, I puted addStretch () in the end of items, everything goes ok, but now, if I put the margin on top or bottom in any widgets, he can shrink or even disappear if the margin is too high . Any way to handle this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `AlignTop`. @JardelMatias see my update (the last paragraph). You can use a `QSpacerItem` to "push" the two line edits to the top.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah, you've also suggested the spacer. Sorry, I only read the first 2 sentences of your comment. :D

Comment: @JardelMatias. The widget margins affect its *contents*, not the space around it. To add space above or below a widget, use the layout spacing/margins, or insert a spacer with a fixed size.

Comment: @rbaleksandar. No problem - I was just suggesting some ways to improve your answer. You've mostly done that now, except for the second paragraph :P

Comment: I actually looked a some one my code from a project and wanted to add it to my answer. For some reason Chrome and Stackoverflow (at least on my Debian) currently are not best friends. I still can't upload an image for example. At least I was able to edit my answer after several hours of not being able to. LOL

Comment: Thanks both, I solved the problem with QSpacerItem(), now is working like I charm.